# Are there any extensions or tricks to reopen several closed tabs in Safari

Tags: macos, tabs, safari, undo

I know Safari 5 (on OSX) allows undoing of a recently closed tab with `Cmd-Z`. However, that works only for the very last closed tab. That is, I cannot press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> twice to reopen the last two closed tabs.

Except for searching my history for the last few tabs, does anyone know of a trick (or extension) in Safari that allows me to reopen last several closed tabs?

Chrome and Firefox offer this simple feature by default: I can press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> twice to reopen the last two closed tabs.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote one. [*retab*](https://github.com/bucaran/retab), and you can customize the key-bindings to match Chrome's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> too. I left it unchecked by default, but you can enable it via *settings*  <kbd>⌘</kbd> +<kbd>,</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: How is the stability and battery efficiency of this?

Why on earth don't Apple just add this?

Comment: Working well for me on a 2014 MBP.

Comment: Having used this for longer now - it has several bugs. For example - tabs A, B, C, D are open. You are on tab B. You close tab C. It works. But if you close the active tab - B - then it just doesn't work.

Comment: Please update to the latest version and check out this [demonstration video](https://github.com/bucaran/retab#demonstration) that shows the behavior is consistent. If that still fails, please open an issue in the issue tracker and let's take it from there.

Comment: I'm on 2.0 - I installed the extension for the first time less than a week ago - auto update extensions is also on (unclear how I update it). I just opened two new tabs, closed, then pressed cmd shift t - nothing - also closing background tabs also no longer works. Bad bugs here...

Comment: Are you using El Capitan? If you are, there is a bug I still haven't fixed that only occurs there. If you are not, then this is certainly a bug. I can't help if I can't replicate it, so it would be really useful if you could [open an issue](https://github.com/bucaran/retab/issues) about this.

Comment: nope - yosemite. FYI - I'm using ghostly & adblock plus as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking to undo *unintentional* closing of tabs, but you could always use the 'Add Bookmark for these tabs' option under the bookmark menu to save them...

Comment: Yes, I indeed was looking for ways to undo _unintentional_ tab-close. Which is why bookmark for all tabs all the time before closing a tab because I don't which tab (if ever) I might need to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Sessions](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8247646/sessions/index.html) is one of my favorite extensions for Safari, you can basically configure it to auto-bookmark all open tabs/windows every so often in its own manager (database) separate from safari. You can import/export this to other users and for backup too. However, you might overwrite your current 'session' if the auto-backup has run after you closed the relevant tabs...
2. Also, [MacHangout.com](http://MacHangout.com) offers an 'add-on' (not strictly speaking an approved 'extension') that allows multiple-undo. After install it will show up in *Safari>Preferences>Glims>Tabs Misc.>* **"Undo ''Close Tab'' (cmd-z)"**

Comment: I use both of these concurrently btw, I didn't just '***gle it'.

Comment: The MacHangout.com link is broken.

Comment: @BrechtMachiels hmmm.... just tried, works for me at this moment.