# Safari: how to re-open MULTIPLE previously closed tabs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tabs, safari, osx-mountain-lion

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> in Safari (6.0.1) will re-open the last closed tab. Is there any way to re-open *multiple* previously closed tabs (as in, say, Chrome)?

A closely related question from 2011: [Are there any extensions or tricks to reopen several closed tabs in Safari](https://superuser.com/questions/254511/are-there-any-extensions-or-tricks-to-reopen-several-closed-tabs-in-safari)

### Update

Safari is now at 6.0.2: having the ability to re-open *multiple* closed tabs would still very much improve usability (i.e. not having to go searching the History). Is the answer still "impossible"?

Comment: At the new Safari `Version 8.0 (10538.46)` from Yosemite beta OS X, the option is still "impossible" as far as I searched =(

Comment: The answer [just changed to possible](http://superuser.com/questions/254511/are-there-any-extensions-or-tricks-to-reopen-several-closed-tabs-in-safari/869451#869451).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the add-on Glims from [MacHangout.com](http://MacHangout.com)

For a more in depth answer, please see [the question you referenced](https://superuser.com/questions/254511/are-there-any-extensions-or-tricks-to-reopen-several-closed-tabs-in-safari)
and my answer there for that *most* "closely related" question. I did include in my answer there another suggestion relevant to the discussion spawned from the other (tog22's) answer, but I do think your question is basically the same as the 'original' question asked there.

Comment: Seems a shame to install such a bloated dodgy 'extension' - just to get this one feature that's standard on other browsers. (I'm using Yosemite)

Comment: @niico ''bloated dodgy'' indeed... after a friend upgraded OS X (I forget from what to what) a while back, safari wouldn't open (immediate crash), so I finally diagnosed the cause to be an incompatible version of glims. of course this is one of those rare cases in which you say "hmmm, sometimes it's good to go through the suggested avenues of extending a program..." therefore allowing checks like mozilla's "checking to make sure add-ons are compatible" protocol.